# how to format text content for JSONP response

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a JSON string that is saved to a text file and I cant figure out the exact way to format it for returning via JSONP.
Original File :

```
[{
    "id": "659",
    "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
    "columns": {
        "itemid": "100-mens-suit",
        "displayname": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
        "salesdescription": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        },
        "baseprice": 699,
        "internalid": {
            "name": "659",
            "internalid": "659"
        }
    }
}]
```

since i have to prepare it by hand, is the correct format

```
callback(
    [{
        "id": "659",
        "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
        "columns": {
            "itemid": "100-mens-suit",
            "displayname": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
            "salesdescription": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
            "type": {
                "name": "Inventory Item",
                "internalid": "InvtPart"
            },
            "baseprice": 699,
            "internalid": {
                "name": "659",
                "internalid": "659"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

or

```
callback({
    [{
        "id": "659",
        "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
        "columns": {
            "itemid": "100-mens-suit",
            "displayname": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
            "salesdescription": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
            "type": {
                "name": "Inventory Item",
                "internalid": "InvtPart"
            },
            "baseprice": 699,
            "internalid": {
                "name": "659",
                "internalid": "659"
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

I cant seem to get it right in any of the JSON format tools, but I expect thats because none validate to JSONP.

Any tips greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's being read from a text file you need to use JSON.parse() before it goes to your callback - if you are just writing it to a callback I would personally declare it like this:

```
var obj = {
    "id": "659",
    "recordtype": "inventoryitem",
    "columns": {
        "itemid": "100-mens-suit",
        "displayname": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
        "salesdescription": "Mens Mid Grey 2 reg Suit",
        "type": {
            "name": "Inventory Item",
            "internalid": "InvtPart"
        },
        "baseprice": 699,
        "internalid": {
            "name": "659",
            "internalid": "659"
        }
    }
};

callback(obj);
```

Out of curiosity is there a reason some of your int's are wrapped as strings?

Comment: Also is there a reason you are wrapping it in an array?  Since there is only a single object there is no reason for `[ ]`.

Comment: the JSON string was very long, so i just cut it down 1 block to keep it shorter here on stackoverflow. 

in regards to the ints being stored as strings, its a legacy thing Ive inherited as its a seperate process that generates the txt file to begin with.